# CSV String to Table using MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, csv, stored-procedures

StoredProcedure(in csvString varchar(1000))

csvString has 1,2,3,4,5,6

I want this csv string into a table like below

[image: Expected output]

if csv string is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 then

[image: Expected output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could elaborate on the problem and put the expected results within your question (for instance in the code formatted section), also you should first write some code yourself and then ask when you get stuck - please read [ask].

Comment: You can write a function to split the string and return odd and even values and save reslectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate and adjust as necessary:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_split`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `split_str`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
    ->   `col1` VARCHAR(255),
    ->   `col2` VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- MySQL Split String Function by Federico Cargnelutti
mysql> -- http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `split_str` (
    -> `str` TEXT,
    -> `delim` CHAR(1),
    -> `item` INT UNSIGNED
    -> ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_current_str` TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`, `delim`, `item`);
    ->   DECLARE `_prev_str` TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`, `delim`, `item`-1);
    ->   IF `_current_str` = `_prev_str` THEN
    ->     RETURN NULL;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     RETURN REPLACE(
    ->       SUBSTRING(
    ->         `_current_str`,
    ->         CHAR_LENGTH(`_prev_str`) + 1
    ->       ),
    ->     `delim`, '');
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_split`(`str` TEXT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_delim` CHAR(1) DEFAULT ',';
    ->   DECLARE `_iteration` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `_current_value` VARCHAR(255);
    ->   DECLARE `_odd_value` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    ->   `repeat`: LOOP
    ->     SET `_iteration` := `_iteration` + 1;
    ->     SET `_current_value` := `split_str`(`str`, `_delim`, `_iteration`);
    ->     IF `_current_value` IS NULL THEN
    ->       LEAVE `repeat`;
    ->     END IF;
    ->     IF (`_iteration` MOD 2) = 0 THEN
    ->       INSERT INTO `tbl` (`col1`, `col2`)
    ->       VALUES (NULLIF(`_odd_value`, ''), NULLIF(`_current_value`, ''));
    ->     ELSE
    ->       SET `_odd_value` := `_current_value`;
    ->     END IF;
    ->   END LOOP `repeat`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `insert_split`('1,2,3,4,5,6');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 5    | 6    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_split`('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 5    | 6    |
| 7    | 8    |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXWt8ma4nF6UsVYCLg1VKS/5).

**UPDATE**

If you use odd and even values, you can use the following:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_split`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `split_str`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
    ->   `col1` VARCHAR(255),
    ->   `col2` VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> -- MySQL Split String Function by Federico Cargnelutti
mysql> -- http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `split_str` (
    -> `str` TEXT,
    -> `delim` CHAR(1),
    -> `item` INT UNSIGNED,
    -> `max_len_str` SMALLINT UNSIGNED
    -> ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_current_str` TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`, `delim`, `item`);
    ->   DECLARE `_prev_str` TEXT DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`str`, `delim`, `item`-1);
    ->   IF `_current_str` = `_prev_str` AND CHAR_LENGTH(`_prev_str`) = `max_len_str`  THEN
    ->     RETURN NULL;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     RETURN REPLACE(
    ->       SUBSTRING(
    ->         `_current_str`,
    ->         CHAR_LENGTH(`_prev_str`) + 1
    ->       ),
    ->     `delim`, '');
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_split`(`str` TEXT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_max_length_str` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT CHAR_LENGTH(`str`);
    ->   DECLARE `_delim` CHAR(1) DEFAULT ',';
    ->   DECLARE `_iteration` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `_odd_value`, `_even_value` VARCHAR(255);
    ->   `repeat`: LOOP
    ->     SET `_odd_value` := `split_str`(`str`, `_delim`, `_iteration` + 1, `_max_length_str`);
    ->     SET `_even_value` := `split_str`(`str`, `_delim`, `_iteration` + 2, `_max_length_str`);
    ->     IF `_odd_value` IS NULL AND `_even_value` IS NULL THEN
    ->       LEAVE `repeat`;
    ->     END IF;
    ->     INSERT INTO `tbl` (`col1`, `col2`)
    ->     VALUES (NULLIF(`_odd_value`, ''), NULLIF(`_even_value`, ''));
    ->     SET `_iteration` := `_iteration` + 2;
    ->   END LOOP `repeat`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_split`('1,2,3,4,5,6');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 5    | 6    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_split`('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 5    | 6    |
| 7    | 8    |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_split`(',,,');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_split`(',1,,,3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `col1`, `col2`
    -> FROM `tbl`;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| NULL | 1    |
| NULL | NULL |
| 3    | NULL |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXWt8ma4nF6UsVYCLg1VKS/6).

Comment: And according to my requirement, i will be receiving 11 multiple csv string. And i need to insert it into 11 columns. I though of changing the logic according to it. But looks like we use even and Odd values here. Again its a dead end for me for 11 column logic. Is there anyway that I can get help from you... Thanks in advance...